# How to search for a composite word using ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I have been using Elasticsearch for a while, but I cannot seem to find an analyzer that solves this particular issue:
I have a document that contains the following text:

```
"The Harry Potter and the Sorcerer Stone is a great book".
```

If the user types "harrypotter" (without spaces), I need to be able to display that document as a search result. Is it possible? 
I looked at Ngram, but it does not seem to fix this scenario coz with Ngram, I would have to store the whole document as:

```
"TheHarryPotterandtheSorcererStoneisagreatbook".
```

Which is not what I want coz if the user searches "harry potter stone", the document will not show up too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit", "whitespace"] in your ngram configuration to also index the whitespaces, which will match your query "harry potter stone" and "harrypotter"

ref:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Edit:
You could also index the 'ngram' version in an inner-field and then query both the normal analyzed field and the ngram field (wrapped in a bool query)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, let me try it out first.